Is there a faster way to calculate transitive modulo exponentiation?
Given a modulo exponentiation problem of the form:
$b^a \pmod {P} =v_0$
$v_0 \pmod {Q} =v_1$, where $Q<P$. Calculate $v_1$.
The default way to calculate $v_1$ would be calculate $v_0$ and then calculate $v_1$. But, is there a faster/cleverer way to calculate this transitive modulus (without this default two step approach)?

Yes: try $v_1 = b^a\pmod{\gcd(P,Q)}$.

@Dennis $2^{11} (mod\ 13)=7$ and then $7 (mod\ 5)=2$.  Thus, $v_0=7, v_1=2, P=13, Q=5$. Can you please clarify what you mean?

Ah, what I was saying would just say that the answer would be $\equiv 0 \equiv 2^{11} \pmod{1}$, since $\gcd(5, 13)=1$, but that is saying nothing at all.

An odd thing about your procedure is that it depends on which representative is chosen for $v_0$: if you instead chose $2^{11} \equiv 20 \pmod{13}$, you get $20 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.

Can you offer any context for where this computation is showing up?

I was simply studying modular exponentiation. Its a very natural Q (at least acc. to me) which i didn't see addressed anywhere.

Generally $,(x\bmod P)\bmod Q,$ is not well-defined unless $,Q\mid P.,$ There are prior questions about this.

@BillDubuque Thank you. So just to reiterate, two step is the only known approach (in general case)?

I'm going to write $x \equiv_m y$ to mean that $x = km + y$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is usually written as $x \equiv y \pmod{m}$. This is the more natural way to think of modular arithmetic: not as an operation (finding a specific remainder after dividng by $m$), but as a relation that a pair of numbers $(x, y)$ can satisfy: "they're the same if you throw away multiples of $m$".
It is true that any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ has a unique integer $y \in \{0, \dots, m-1\}$ satisfying $x\equiv_m y$, but there's no fundamental reason to pick the set $\{0, \dots, m-1\}$, instead of $\{1, \dots, m\}$, or $\{2, \dots, m+1\}$, etc. The action of choosing a representative from each congruence class is an unnatural step, so it makes the procedure not so nice algebraically.
Something that is true is that given $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b \in \mathbb{N}$, an integer $v_1$ satisfies $b^a \equiv_{\gcd(P,Q)} v_1$ if and only if there exists an integer $v_0$ satisfying $b^a \equiv_P v_0$ and $v_0\equiv_Q v_1$. Here's a proof:

For "if", assuming $b^a \equiv_P v_0 \equiv_Q v_1$, since $\gcd(P,Q)$ divides $P$ and $Q$, we can refine this to $b^a \equiv_{\gcd(P,Q)} v_0 \equiv_{\gcd(P,Q)} v_1$ to conclude that $b^a \equiv_{\gcd(P,Q)} v_1$.

For "only if", assume $b^a = v_1 + k\gcd(P,Q)$, and write $\gcd(P,Q) = mP+nQ$ for some $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, so then $b^a = v_1 + kmP + knQ$. Then take $v_0 = v_1 + knQ$, so then $b^a = v_0 + kmP \equiv_{P} v_0$ and $v_0 = v_1 + knQ \equiv_Q v_1$.


(You could actually replace $b^a$ with a new variable $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and this would be equally valid.) But the point is that after computing both modulo $P$ and modulo $Q$, the only information you have left that modular arithmetic can give you is the information modulo $\gcd(P,Q)$. If $Q$ divides $P$ then $\gcd(P,Q)=Q$, so this is everything you want, but in general, your procedure isn't "playing the game" of modular arithmetic, so it's not going to be very nicely predictable.

Said more simply $\ (n+p\Bbb Z)+q\Bbb Z ,=, n + (p\Bbb Z + q\Bbb Z) ,=, n + \gcd(p,q)\Bbb Z\ \ $

More generally: $,R/P,/:(Q!+!P)/P,\cong, R/(Q!+!P),$ for ideals $,P,Q\subset R.\ \ $
